# Axios basic authorization not going through in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication, api-design, axios

First time asking so here I go.

I'm trying to make a GET call to a stormpath app my team made which requires some authorization. When using Postman to test and after some configuration it everything came out 200.

[Results of API call in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD3Yz.png)

Using curl worked

```
curl --verbose --user ID:SECRET -H "Accept: application/json" https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current
...
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, no-transform
< Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 09:27:14 GMT
< Location: https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/TENANTID
< Pragma: no-cache
< Stormpath-Request-Id: f8e4dee0-d716-11e6-9795-22000aa92aa2
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.stormpath.com left intact
```

But when I tried to make a call through `Axios` in `React` I get a 401 error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

This is what I used:

```
axios({ 
method: 'get',
url: "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current", 
auth:
{
    username: 'api ID',
    password: 'api Secret'
}
})
```

I don't know why but it's not delivering the username and password according to the response I got.

```
code:401
developerMessage:"Authentication with a valid API Key is required."
message:"Authentication required."
moreInfo:"http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect"
requestId:"3686f590-d69e-11e6-9b8a-22000a8ce5d1"
status:401
```

It appears similar questions has been asked before but there are still no responses for them.

[Reactjs Axios / Spring boot security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842068/reactjs-axios-spring-boot-security)

[Cannot Basic Auth from React App with Axios or SuperAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468803/cannot-basic-auth-from-react-app-with-axios-or-superagent)

[Basic authentication : failure supergaent+OSX , success on superagent+Redhat , success on Postman+OSX,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064018/basic-authentication-failure-supergaentosx-success-on-superagentredhat-s)

Thanks's for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Probably an invalid API key/secret, as the error is saying.

Comment: The API key/secret works just fine using Postman. I even used the API key/secret to access the API through the address bar and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

Got this same problem couple months ago and end up with the same solution. I think it related to cors in the front end since you try to hit other domain for the api.

And you add some custom auth data to the header, so you may need to use 'withCredentials: true' when you make the call. Then it will cause a preflight options call issue. And I don't think it should handle in the front-end. Hope this help.

Comment: I tried adding withCredentials: true and  it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I couldn't figure out why `axios` auth call wasn't working but I found a way to get through. What I did was make the auth API call inside `express` instead of in `React`.

So what is happening is `React` makes a call to my server localhost.

```
axios.get("/secret")
    .then(
        function(response)
        {
            console.log(response)
        }
    )
```

Then node/express server catches it and runs the API call I want. I used `request` and `cors`

```
app.use(cors());

...

app.get('/secret', function(req, res){

    var queryUrl = "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenant/current;
    request({url:queryUrl,   auth: {
    user: ID,
    pass: SECRET
  }}, function(err, response, body){

        if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
            info = JSON.parse(body);
            res.send(info);
        }
        else{
            res.send(err)
        }
    })
})
```

And it worked with all the stormpath API URLs that I need.